# Refresh schema won't retrieve columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Can you give me some advice on how to enable refresh schema so I can use it to (re)generate GridView columns:

- With ObjectDataSource controls refresh schema link works ( thus retrieves information from data source ) only when I change a property in a data source ( for example, if I make public property into private one ) and then re-compile the web page, and even then refresh schema will retrieve property names only the first time I click on it. 
  Thus if ( after I already clicked refresh schema link once ) I remove from GridView  tags, but I then want to regenerate those columns using refresh schema link, it wont work!
- Similary, with Sqldatasource refresh schema link works only if I change the SelectCommand string and even then only once.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing refresh schema, I think you are going to need to turn AutoGenerateColumns on